# NSURLError Domain: iOS 9 error code: -1022

Tags: ios9

I am working on an iOS App. The app is working fine when I am running on different iOS versions e.g. 7.1, 8.3, 8.4 but I am facing an issue when I am trying to run the app on iOS 9 beta (on Simulator).

I went through several links, one way was mentioned somewhere that by adding the following snippet to the info.plist file it would work but unfortunately this is also not working for me.

```
 <key> NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Also found this

```
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
```

But this is also not working. What I have understood after visiting several links is that in iOS 9 Apple won't let you enter using an unsecured connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen if you are using a hard-coded IP address. iOS9 doesn't support it. Also, since you haven't provided enough details, it might also be the case that you are trying to access some URL that has a URL scheme associated with it e.g. instagram://; In that case you need to specify a whitelist for such URL schemes for which you can Refer to : [Is there an alternative to (the deprecated) canOpenURL in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470784/is-there-an-alternative-to-the-deprecated-canopenurl-in-ios-9)

Comment: Thanks !! i found the answer :)

Comment: btw i was not using hardcoded IP addresses.. adding key to the info.plist worked for me